# Grouping columns in Google spreadsheets (and summarize them)

Tags: google-sheets

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
A | B | C

1 | 4 | 3
```

Is it possible to group these columns together so that I can expand and collapse them with a specific formula. For example with `SUM` I would have one single column:

```
ABC

 8
```

And after that expand them again if I need the detailed data.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with hiding/unhiding columns but not possible with a formula.